# Images are broken while rendering in Home Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, carousel

I have created a LWC component and pasted it on the Home Page. In this component I am just trying to create an image carousel. I have downloaded a three sample images and created a zip file which I uploaded in my Static Resource. Although the carousel is showing but the images are all broken and I also see that apart from one picture in a slide, a part of the other picture is also appearing in it as shown below:
[image]

**.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Salesforce_Images from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/educationCarousel';
export default class ShowImage extends LightningElement {
    image1 = Salesforce_Images + '/images/image1.jpg';
    image2 = Salesforce_Images + '/images/image2.jpg';
    image3 = Salesforce_Images + '/images/image3.jpg';
  }
```

**.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-carousel>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src={image1}
                    header="First Image">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src={image2}
                    header="Second Image">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src={image3}
                    header = "Third Image">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
            </lightning-carousel>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I would really appreciate some help to solve these two issues.

Comment: they are not broken - check the network tab to see what status you get from each on loading. your image paths may not be correct.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the image paths. Try printing the generated paths using `console.log(image1);` and then check if paths are correct or not.

Comment: It says "https://mightguy-dev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1647612838000/educationCarousel/images/image1.jpg 404 (Not Found)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake initially while writing the .js file. The correct code is:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Salesforce_Images from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/educationCarousel';
export default class ShowImage extends LightningElement {
    image1 = Salesforce_Images + '/education/Pic1.jpg';
    image2 = Salesforce_Images + '/education/Pic2.jpeg';
    image3 = Salesforce_Images + '/education/Pic3.jpg';
}
```

I made a mistake in the path of the images I used as static resource. The .zip file when opened will show "education" folder and inside it there are the files "Pic1.jpg", "Pic2.jpeg" and "Pic3.jpg".